# Issue tracker for web agency workflow

Tags: issue-tracking

We're looking into implementing an issue tracker for our web agency. The problem is that most issue trackers seem to revolve around the assumption that an issue is a bug, whereas in a web agency environment, a lot of the issues (request, or whatever you want to call them) are about changes and additions to a current web site.

It also seems to me that a lot of issue trackers assume that you're working on one main software project, and uses that project as the focus of the tracker. A good issue tracker for a web agency would be one which puts each separate client and their issues at the heart of the system, making it easy for them to track and report issues.

Does anyone know of a good issue tracker for the web agency workflow? What are other people using?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, issue trackers are so closely coupled to the workflow of the organisation that what works in one place may be a complete misfit in another. That said, could basecamp work for you?

Comment: In my experience, Basecamp does not provide enough detail to properly categorize and prioritize tasks. At least not for us, anyway.

Comment: I agree that issue trackers are mostly coupled with an organisation's workflow but as Eirik describes, web agencies tend to have quite similar workflows across the board. The great thing with basecamp is that it doesn't impose workflow. I personally think workflow is something that needs to be enforced in the human/operational process than the actual tool.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [Gemini](http://www.geminiplatform.com) very flexible with the ability to have workflow at the project level.

But where Gemini really helps us is the cross project views. You can view your work across all projects with really good fitering.

Comment: I recently reviewed them, but the uninformative videos with the techno music on top really put me off.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at [fixx](http://hedgehoglab.com/products/fixx/) at all? Obviously, being the developer of fixx, I will want to plug it but I know from first-hand experience that a lot of our customers are web agencies who work in a service-oriented environment and need to track more than just "software development" projects.

With fixx, you can define custom issue types (for example "change request" or "Copy changes") and track work against that type.

Unfortunately, fixx still does suffer from the "project-centric" view but a lot of our customers work around this by defining a project per client/website. So, if you were doing web/maintenance on stackoverflow.com, you would have a project called "stackoverflow.com maintenance" and would assign all your users from that company to that specific project. From there, using notifications and filters, it would be very easy for clients to keep track of progress on their specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

[FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) – it's simple by default, but extensible; it's got an integrated wiki, charts, tags, and you can even tie it to your source-control system (and they also offer their own integrated source control system, [Kiln](http://www.fogcreek.com/kiln/), which is pretty amazing with FogBugz).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using other applications to manage the rest of your business' operations?

I ask because WORKetc has great issue tracking software, and this software is combined with other aspects of business management which can simplify the management process. So not only could you manage all support inquiries and responses in one place, but also your projects, finances, and contacts. Most importantly, it would allow you to use one central contact base for your entire company, while allowing you to reference that contact information (as well as lead information) while working on support inquiries, projects, invoices, etc.

WORKetc's support system works around email integration and simple ticket system (as well as prioritizing) and directly integrates with projects, contacts, and other aspects of the system so that you can save time while responding and managing tickets.

Answer (score 0):

I think especially for the use case of a web-agency, where it's not really about bugs, but mostly (visual) feedback and all of it happens on the web, a visual feedback tool might be the thing you're looking for. Most of these tools will create a screenshot of the webpage and include the given feedback on it. 
Some of them also have some kind of dashboard where you can discuss further, or have integrations to other tools like Basecamp (and some them do both).

Here's an [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/09/essential-visual-feedback-tools-for-web-designers/) from smashing magazine, which describes a lot of them, e.g.: [TrackDuck](https://trackduck.com), [BugMuncher](https://www.bugmuncher.com). Another great tool the article doesn't mention, maybe because the article is a bit dated, is [Usersnap](https://www.usersnap.com) – this one even includes browser extensions.